# accessing an NFS share from java

Tags: java, nfs

I'm trying to sort out a way to access an NFS share (ideally all privileges, but I'll settle for read only for now) from our application in Java. I've spent most of the day researching and the closest I came was the [yanfs project](https://java.net/projects/yanfs) (nee [WebNFS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1067/6jacl3e62/index.html)) but it doesn't seem to have been updated since the aughties and it doesn't have any documentation either. I ran some low grade experiments with it but those were unsuccessful.

Because of the nature of our application, I can't pre-mount the volumes (there could be zero to many) and I would like to avoid calling `sudo mount` inside the program if at all possible. Unfortunately this approach is the only semi-viable solution I can come up with. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Also: No modern NFS java client libraries? Really? That can't possibly be right.

Comment: might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/1864341/3166303

Comment: What "volumes" are you trying to mount? Intranet, extranet, B2B, B2C, ..?

Comment: NFS shares, probably from things like Isilon appliances, but it might be other types as well. I THINK we can get away with the requirement that we're in the same subnet, but that's not a solid fact. I forgot to mention that the requirement is also to support NFS 4.0 as well.

Comment: I wouldn't expect many NFS clients (or libraries) written in Java. The OS already handles it so I wouldn't expect much interest in reimplementing it.  Maybe take a look at [FUSE}(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). autofs can help, too, or listing the mount points in /etc/fstab with the 'user' option.

Comment: FUSE looks interesting except the windows client project (doken) appears to be dead. I've got to be able to use it on multiple platforms
the etc/fstab thing might be an option, but it seems a little messy: I would have to get the list of nfs shares the user wants to add, append that to the fstab (needing root to do so), and then re-running mount (again with root privileges).
The autofs thing seems promising. Windows appears to have an automount system, I'm currently trying to see if its similar enough to use.

Comment: I would think that even if people don't want to reimplement the nfs client, there might still be a need to access the nfs client from java. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since time is of the essence, we're going to cheat a bit for now. So this is the solution I worked out in case anyone comes along later.
I looked into [autofs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs) like @dsh suggested. With Autofs I set up the `/etc/auto.master` file to have the following line:

```
/mnt/fromNFS    /usr/local/etc/auto.fromNFS --timeout=60
```

I then touched the `/usr/local/etc/auto.fromNFS` and changed its ownership to the user and group that is to run the app. 
Now I can anagrammatically modify the auto.fromFNS file to include lines for the given nfs share. When I then go to access that directory, it nicely gets mounted with no need to `sudo`.
Its not ideal but it looks like it will get the job done for now.
Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Comment: I've created a java library that can do this automatically for you.
https://github.com/Seven10Storage/nfs-mounter

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out this library https://github.com/dCache/nfs4j ?

It has a server and client pure java implementation for NFSv3, NFSv4 and NFS4.1.

It is a bit low level and it does NOT provide simple usage like XFile in yaNFS.

So you have to do a bit of work to read and write to files, But at least it gets the job done, Accessing NFS exports without mounting.

You can find some file access examples at the project repo.

Comment: Heh, we actually decided to use this just after you posted this link. thanks!

Comment: @KevinMilner: How effort-some was it for you to click a +1 button for somebody who answers your question. I see you had taken to effort to write a thanks. But, the answer had 0 upvotes.

Comment: @bhrt I'm usually pretty generous in giving upvotes. If I commented on this (which I did) I almost certainly gave an upvote. Someone else could have downvoted this answer. But thanks for jumping on me without any evidence.